# Position a submit button inside div

Tags: html, css, position, height

Hi I am having some problems with the positioning of a submit button. I have posted the code below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="search">
  <form action="post">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.search {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  height: 30px;
  width: 280px;
  color: #4D4C4C;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189,0.8);
}
input[type="submit"] {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Here is an image showing the output. My problem is that there is a small space above the submit button and I cant find out why since they both have height set to 30px . I want the button to have the same height as the .search div. Height: 100% does not seem to work.

http://i57.tinypic.com/atswm0.png

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
input[type="submit"] {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am quite new to html and css so this was really helpful!